# Disable login prompt through SSH when no key is present

Tags: openssh

I've set OpenSSH server with private/public keys, with password login disabled.

I was wondering if there was a way to not even show the 'login:' prompt when someone without a key tries to connect.

**EDIT**

Okay ... There seems to be some confusion as to what I'm trying to achieve. So, here's a better explanation (I hope) ...

**Current setup**

Client with key connects, and goes through the process:

```
login as: username
BANNER
Authenticating with public key "Key name"
Passphrase for key "key name": *******
Welcome
username@hostname:~$
```

Client without key connects, and goes through process:

```
login as: username
BANNER
Server refused our key
```

**What I want**

client without key connects, and goes through process:

```
No key, go away.
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898384/ssh-disable-password-authentication

Comment: Nah that's to disable the 'password:' prompt

Comment: The keys on the server side are typically stored in `~/.ssh`, i.e. a user-specific directory, so it makes sense that you would always have to provide a username one way or another; it has to know which keys to compare. If you have the same username on each machine then SSH without a username assumes the one you are connecting to is the username on your local machine.

Comment: How will the Server know which key to try if you have not identified a user? SSH won't run through every key on file in the hope that something fits. That would all kinds of problems. The simplest way to avoid the login prompt is to include the username in the ssh connection command: `ssh homerjsimpson@servername.org`

Answer (score 5):

On the server side, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so that you have the line:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

then restart the server:

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

That will remove the ability to authenticate without a key.

However, you will always have to identify yourself, so you can't remove the login prompt.

If you use `ssh username@hostname` to connect, you'll never see it, but others will if they connect to the hostname with no username.

You can limit access to only your username with a key if you add to the above:

```
AllowUsers username
```

For this and other things, see the [Ubuntu wiki page for SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring).

Comment: Erm ... Yeah I've already done that ... But doesn't change the normal behavior of showing the 'login:' prompt when someone connects to the server.

Comment: Without a key, it should give: `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: It still shows the 'login as:' prompt

Comment: Edited to provide a more authoritative answer. Sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yeah, what I'm trying to achieve, is when clients connect to the hostname, that the 'login as:' prompt is disabled (Without a key) ... So this answer still doesn't work

Comment: What I'm saying is there is no way to do what you want. You will always need to identify yourself. Unless you edit the OpenSSH server code :-)

Comment: Well that's a kick in the nuts

Comment: Yeah not every question can be answered with a likable answer :-)

Comment: `sudo service ssh restart` no ?

Comment: @Jean-LucBarat same difference, actually.